# Join pattern line and consecutive non-empty lines, separated by commas and enclosed in ()

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, osx

I have a file that has

```
click
css_add_violation_false

click
css_add_claim_false
```

and

```
select
css_driver1_birth_date_month
birth_date_month

select
css_driver1_birth_date_day
birth_date_day
```

How could I replace the click[newline]value with click(value)?
or click[newline]value[newline]value with click(value,value)

I couldn't figure it out with `sed` probably because it's not good for multi-line stuff.

I tried using `tr` to remove the carriage return with

```
tr 'select\n' 'select('
```

but that removed all the carriage returns and added lots of `(`

(note: osx)

Desired Output:

```
click(css_add_violation_false)
click(css_add_claim_false)
```

and

```
select(css_driver1_birth_date_month, birth_date_month)
select(css_driver1_birth_date_day, birth_date_day
```

Will be a good more general answer if it can handle any number of params until a blank line is seen.

Comment: desired/expected output added.  Thanks.

Comment: Additional condition added at bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{if($0=="click"){getline n;printf "%s(%s)\n", $0, n}else{print}}' file
```

If the line matches `click`, load the next line in a varable called `n` and then print the desired output format.

**Edit:**

If there is a variable number of multiple lines and you want to combine them until the empty line occures, use this:

```
awk '{if($0=="click"){getline n; printf "%s(%s", $0, n;
  while($0!=""){printf ",%s", $0; getline};
  printf ")\n\n", x}else{print}}' file
```

It prints the lines comma-separated, until it finds an empty line.

Comment: This is great! Is there any way it could handle multiple lines ? (see updated example)

Comment: How about: `awk '{if($0=="select"){getline n;getline n2; printf "%s(%s, %s)\n", $0, n, n2}else{print}}'` for the multi-line.  Not sure how to combine the two.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

`perl` is good tool for this job:

```
$ perl -p00e 's/click\n(.*)\n/click(\1)\n/' file
click(css_add_violation_false)

click(css_add_claim_false)
```

Answer (score 0):

For **GNU sed**

```
sed -Ez 's/(click)\n([^\n]*)/\1(\2)/g'
```

or old-style

```
sed '/click/{N;s/\n/(/;s/$/)/;}'
```

Comment: thanks but `-r` not available on osx (tagged and noted in question)

Comment: @MichaelDurrant in OSX you can use `-E`

Comment: What's `-z`? It's defintely not on my version of GNU sed. Also your old version only puts the direct next line in brackets.